# Google Maps v3 vs IE ... SCRIPT5022

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Like in topic: everywhere my implementation works in FF, Chrome, Opera... IE: SCRIPT5022

i'm initializing Google Maps by Callback coz i had google.maps.MapTypeID undefined issue.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=pl&callback=gmapInit" type="text/javascript"><\/script>
```

and gmapInit:

```
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(print_it.doc.getElementById('location-map'), {
     center                     : new google.maps.LatLng(51.917168,19.138184),
     zoom                       : 6,
     minZoom                    : 6,
     maxZoom                    : 16,
     mapTypeId                  : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
     scrollwheel                : false,
     disableDefaultUI           : true,
     navigationControl          : true,
     navigationControlOptions   : {
           style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
     }
  });
```

print_it.doc is reference to document in new window
and IE fails in this.map = new google.maps.Map(..... );

plz help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an scope-issue.

In IE it's not possible to move nodes between documents.

So what will happen when you  intialize the map from the opener:

1. the API will access the target-div inside the new window(no problem
   so far)
2. the API will create lot's of elements to build the map(the API will do this in the scope of the current document, not inside the new window, the problems start)
3. the API needs to put the created elements to the map, but in IE this will fail, because the elements have been created in a different document(inside the opener) and must be moved to the new window.

What you can do:
Also include the maps-API inside the new window and use the google-object inside the new window for all calls related to the map inside the new window:

**example**:

(assuming print_it is a window-object and you included the maps-API inside the new window)

```
this.map = new print_it.google.maps.Map(print_it.doc.getElementById('location-map'), {
     center                     : new print_it.google.maps.LatLng(51.917168,19.138184),
     zoom                       : 6,
     minZoom                    : 6,
     maxZoom                    : 16,
     mapTypeId                  : print_it.google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
     scrollwheel                : false,
     disableDefaultUI           : true,
     navigationControl          : true,
     navigationControlOptions   : {
           style: print_it.google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
     }
  });
```

Comment: it doesnt helped me directly, but you gave me very good point! thanks!